# Could not find kotlin plug-in

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

after starting an new project the following error appeared in Android Studio???

What should I do?

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'StartActivity'.
```

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0-release-764.

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app"s APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official
```

Comment: Can you post your project level `build.gradle` file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67435751/build-gradle-file-could-not-compile

Comment: It's fixed in Android Studio 4.2.1: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/05/android-studio-421-available.html

Answer (score 0):

The current workaround is to replace version '1.5.0-release-764' with version '1.5.0' in the project's build.gradle files.

Android 4.2.1 has fixed it when creating new Kotlin projects, but for older projects you have to replace the version.
It should be fixed on kotlin 1.5.1
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-11590