# build.gradle file could not compile

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

This error appears when I run my project:

Could not compile build file `'H:\StartActivity\build.gradle'`.

> startup failed:
> build file 'H:\StartActivity\build.gradle': 28: only buildscript {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0-release-764"
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        }
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
    plugins {
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.5.0-release-764'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    }
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's fixed in Android Studio 4.2.1: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/05/android-studio-421-available.html

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Changing ext.kotlin_version to 1.5.0 is working :)

Answer (score 0):

You should move plugins{...} before allprojects{...}

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0-release-764"
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    plugins {
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.5.0-release-764'
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        }
    }
    
....
```